# Instalar matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

estou tentando instalar o matplotlib no computador mas estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0dwfwkh3\matplotlib\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0dwfwkh3\matplotlib\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0dwfwkh3\matplotlib\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0dwfwkh3\matplotlib\
    Complete output (205 lines):
    ================================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

```
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
  matplotlib: yes [3.1.1]
      python: yes [3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC
                  v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]]
    platform: yes [win32]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
 sample_data: yes [installing]
       tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
         agg: yes [installing]
       tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl/Tk]
      macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]

OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
        dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
Could not locate executable f90
Could not locate executable DF
Could not locate executable efl
Could not locate executable gfortran
Could not locate executable f95
Could not locate executable g95
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
Could not locate executable flang
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
'svnversion' nÆo ‚ reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa oper vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
Running from numpy source directory.
C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-oua2om1c\numpy-1.17.3\setup.py:418: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
  run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-oua2om1c\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
    Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
    Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
    A better performance should be easily gained by switching
    Blas library.
  self.calc_info()
C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-oua2om1c\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-oua2om1c\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-oua2om1c\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-oua2om1c\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 489, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
    return self.find_available_vc_vers()[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 163, in run
    self.run_command("egg_info")
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-oua2om1c\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", line 26, in run
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-oua2om1c\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 142, in run
  File "C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-oua2om1c\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 153, in build_sources
  File "C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-oua2om1c\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 286, in build_library_sources
  File "C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-oua2om1c\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 369, in generate_sources
  File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 667, in get_mathlib_info
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 241, in try_link
    self._check_compiler()
  File "C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-oua2om1c\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 54, in _check_compiler
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 253, in initialize
    vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 185, in msvc14_get_vc_env
    return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 843, in __init__
    self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 485, in __init__
    self.vc_ver = vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vc_ver()
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 492, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
    raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-oua2om1c\numpy-1.17.3\setup.py", line 443, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-oua2om1c\numpy-1.17.3\setup.py", line 435, in setup_package
  File "C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-oua2om1c\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 171, in setup
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
    raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
SystemExit: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1144, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
    raise
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
    six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-oua2om1c\numpy-1.17.3\setup.py", line 443, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-oua2om1c\numpy-1.17.3\setup.py", line 435, in setup_package
  File "C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-oua2om1c\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 171, in setup
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
    raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
SystemExit: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ferco\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0dwfwkh3\matplotlib\setup.py", line 262, in <module>
    setup(
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 716, in fetch_build_eggs
    resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 786, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 890, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1158, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "c:\users\ferco\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1146, in run_setup
    raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Alguem tem alguma ideia de como resolver?
Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 0):

Tente instalar os seguintes pacotes:

1) [Visual Studio Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16)

Caso não funcione:

2) [Microsoft C++ Build Tools](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/f/7/5f7acaeb-8363-451f-9425-68a90f98b238/visualcppbuildtools_full.exe)

3) [Microsoft Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159)

P.S: Preste atenção na última linha do erro

> distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error:
>   Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual
>   C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/